# Caching DOM changes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am conducting partial caching which is working really well.

However if I change the DOM inside the cache block those changes arn't cached. Is there a way to also include those changes?

Here is what I have so far:

```
<%
cache(@contact.hash_key) do
    %><div id="<%=@contact.hash_key%>"></div><%
end
%>

<script>
    //use ajax to prepend new messages.
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $.get("/messages?cid=<%=@contact.hash_key%>", function(data) {
          $("#<%=@contact.hash_key%>").prepend(data);
       });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Ok so I am trying to attempt to cache the result before it enters the DOM with the same cache key. That way when the cache block is rendered the new data is included with that key.

But I'm not sure the correct way to structure this.

Answer (score 0):

Done!

So for anyone wanting to do the same thing here is a brief outline on how to do it. You may need to make changes or tweak this solution to fit your own.

This will only work if you are using cache keys. In my instance I have 2 types. A `contact.hash_key` and a `message.hash_key`

All message caches are kept inside a parent contact cache. So essentially:

```
<div id='contact-hash'>
    <div id='message-hash-1'>
    <div id='message-hash-2'>
    <div id='message-hash-3'>
```

First of all we need to loop through the messages and see if they are cached. If they are then you can just render the cached copy. You can do this by using the `Rails.cache.read` method:

```
messages.each do |message|
   cache = Rails.cache.read 'views/'+message.hash_key
   if cache.nil? == false
       %><%= cache.html_safe %><%
   end
end
```

So now we have  a list of messages from cache thats already been loaded. So what about new messages? Lets load these via ajax so the user isn't waiting for a boring page load.

You will notice in my question above I have querying `"/messages?cid=<%=@contact.hash_key%>"` in my AJAX call. This is calling the `messages controller` and rendering the `index view`.

Before we want to load the rendered view into the DOM we want to write it to the cache first with, surprise surprise, the identical message.hash_key we are going to use to read it.

So in your view:

```
<%
cache(message[:hash_key]) do
%>
   <div class='message'>
        This is a new message from the server.
   </div>
<%
end
%>
```

If in  some situations this doesn't work (god knows theres so many app permutations out there) you can also use `Rails.cache.write 'foo', 'bar'` in the controller instead of caching it at the view level.

And there you have it. Now you can add the new hash_key to the list and then render the view back to the DOM as the results of your AJAX call.

Now with the new hash_key in the list you can loop over it and it will come up as a cached copy.

This may or may not be the most elegant solution. If someone wants to simplify or give any advice on it so I can improve it that would be much appreciated.